# Handling globally 'No internet connection' in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mobile

Does anyone of you have experience in implementing global handling of 'No internet' in Xamarin Forms?
I would like to avoid checking it there is connection before each navigation, since it makes code really bloated for a feature which is repeated in every view model? (Im talking MVVM pattern). My first thought was MessagingCenter, but im not really fan of it since handling things there can get messy.
Thank you for all hints :)

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/easily-check-mobile-device-connectivity-with-xamarin-essentials/#subscribe-to-connectivity-changes

Comment: why does your app navigation require an internet connection?

Comment: Navigation doesnt need internet connection, but most of the time i would like to 'stop application flow' and present to user view indicating that there is no internet connection. Pretty much every VM in my app fetches something from API when initializing.

Comment: And thanks for the link. Maybe i will combine some event handling with base view model class and Prism functionality, which can set whether view model is eligible for navigation.

Comment: *"Pretty much every VM in my app fetches something from API when initializing."* Then you probably don't want to use one of the "convenience" navigation setups, such as "Shell". Instead, make a static helper method that you call, whenever the user does something that would navigate to a new page. E.g a button press calls `MyNavGoTo(new MyNextPage())`. Where `MyNavGo` does the checking, and then either shows your "No Internet" page, or does `gotoasync(page)`.